# Which instance I'm in, a master then which master?

Tags: kubernetes

I can log into a *work terminal* via a public IP, and list all the `nodes` by

```
kubectl get nodes # only gives me internal IPs
```

and also be able to check the basic info by

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

and the basic IP info for the current instance by:

```
ifconfig # but this gives me public IP not internal
```

The problem is I have no idea how to determine **which node** I am currently in: a `master`? which master (there are several masters) or just a slave? then which slave?

Thanks for the help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these commands might show different output based on your Kubernetes cluster, I am showing examples from GKE here.

You can use `-owide` option to get some additional information:

```
$kubectl get nodes -owide
NAME                           STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION        EXTERNAL-IP      OS-IMAGE            KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
gke-test-pool2-772ceaec-0tzf   Ready     <none>    23h       v1.9.7-gke.5   35.200.255.186   Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.4.111+         docker://17.3.2
gke-test-pool2-772ceaec-1722   Ready     <none>    20h       v1.9.7-gke.5   35.200.152.18    Container-Optimized OS from Google   4.4.111+         docker://17.3.2
```

From the above output you can use:

- External IP - the IP address of node (Might differ based on your setup)
- Roles - in this case are empty indicating slave nodes as master nodes don't get listed in GKE.

Also, you can use labels to get some more information:

```
$ kubectl get --show-labels nodes
NAME                           STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION        LABELS
gke-test-pool2-772ceaec-0tzf   Ready     <none>    23h       v1.9.7-gke.5   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=n1-standard-1,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=pool2,cloud.google.com/gke-preemptible=true,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=asia-south1,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=asia-south1-b,kubernetes.io/hostname=gke-test-pool2-772ceaec-0tzf
gke-test-pool2-772ceaec-1722   Ready     <none>    20h       v1.9.7-gke.5   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true,beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=n1-standard-1,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=pool2,cloud.google.com/gke-preemptible=true,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=asia-south1,failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=asia-south1-b,kubernetes.io/hostname=gke-test-pool2-772ceaec-1722
```

From this output, you can:

- The node pool in labels tells me that it is part of pool2 worker/slave pool
- Hostname in labels might be helpful based on your setup.

You can match above information with `ifconfig` to figure out the IP of your node. Lastly - it is not necessary that the terminal you are logged in is one of the nodes in the cluster.

Lastly, it could very well be a node which is outside cluster with `Kubeconfig` and `kubectl` configured.

Comment: Upvoted, thanks for the detailed clarification, perhaps due to the configuration (set up by others), I still cannot determine the node of the *work terminal*. As for the **last** point you mentioned, how to set up K8s like that outside cluster? Any link I can refer to? Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: @Hearen - Sign up for a free GCP account, you get 300$ to experiment. Create a GKE cluster and then from an additional VM/Cloud bash shell - you can access Kubernetes cluster

Comment: Still I am confused by the **last** point, how can I run some K8s commands in the work terminal if it's outside?

Comment: Suggesting to follow this: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart and in a couple of steps when you configure the cloud shell - you will know.

Comment: Thanks for the help ;) I will look into it to get more details.